# Reading bytes of a file into a structure

Tags: c

How would I go about reading a binary file and assigning their values to a structure? Each structure with its content will be written to a csv file.

I have this [data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AJAjjrniuRT00zRDl1MlpuSUU/view?usp=sharing), it's a list of `struct product` entries.

Here is the `Product` structure in an h file:

```
struct product {
    char code[15];
    char name[50];
    short int quantity;
    double price;
}

typedef struct product *Product;
```

And here is how I'm trying to read each line into the Product structure and writing it to the csv file:

```
File *fp;
File *outFile;
fp = fopen("products.dat", "rb");
outFile = fopen("allproducts.csv", "w");
Product p;

while (fread(p, sizeof(Product), 1, fp) == 1) {
    fwrite(p->code, sizeof(p->code), 1, outFile);
}
```

I don't think I'm reading the file correctly because when I try writing to the file, all I get are the question marks in a box in the csv file.

Comment: Use `fprintf` instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you for that suggestion. However, I'm still getting the same incorrect output in the file

Comment: `p` is pointer type. you not allocate for it. and `sizeof(Product)` is wrong.

Comment: try `struct product p;` .. `fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, fp)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY doing that gave me a segmentation fault

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so instead of `fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, fp)`, I did `fread(p, sizeof(p), 1, fp)` and it got rid of the segmentation fault. But even then, I'm getting the wrong output. I get the odd characters for the strings. And 0's for my quantity and price values.

Comment: `fread(p,` Can't it. 1st argument must be a pointer. Do You do `Product p;` change to `struct product p;` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh no I didn't change it to `struct product p` the first time. But now that I've done that, my output is now correct, so thank you!

Comment: beware of byte alignment and endianness.

Comment: One more telling example of why hiding pointers behind typedefs is error prone and confusing.

Comment: @chqrlie My professor uses the typedef with the pointer, so I implemented her examples into my work thinking it'll help me to compare things in the end. But her way has proven to not be the best method.

Comment: I'm afraid you have a dilemma: you probably should not criticize your professor for giving questionable directions. Just be aware that this practice is rooted in trying to mimic other languages such as Java, where objects are always manipulated via pointers without the need for explicit `*`. In C, it leads to confusing code and should be avoided. It is very difficult to program in C without some genuine understanding of the concept of pointers. Hiding them does not make this difficulty go away, it strikes back immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If the writer of the data file does not take care for the size of the `struct` it writes, the reader has trouble to make sense of it. I played around with it a bit and found out that a small adjustment is needed to get the proper result *on my machine and OS*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ADJUSTMENT 4

struct product {
  char code[15];
  char name[50];
  short int quantity;
  double price;
};

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  //FILE *outFile;
  struct product p;

  fp = fopen("products.dat", "rb");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fopen failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  //outFile = fopen("allproducts.csv", "w");

  while (fread(&p, sizeof(p) - ADJUSTMENT, 1, fp) == 1) {
    printf("CODE: %s\n", p.code);
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It is a well known problem with such simple attempts for writing binary data, it is just not portable and I'm pretty sure that the value of my adjustment does not fit for you. You need to find a method to make it portable.

Comment: Why would you need the adjustment?

Comment: @Rhymoid The compiler might have padded it for better byte alignment, might have used 4 byte `int` instead of 2 byte `short` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your below code needs to be modified.

Your Original Code:

```
File *fp;
File *outFile;
fp = fopen("products.dat", "rb");
outFile = fopen("allproducts.csv", "w");
Product p;

while (fread(p, sizeof(Product), 1, fp) == 1) {
    fwrite(p->code, sizeof(p->code), 1, outFile);
}
```

Modified Code:

```
File *fp;
File *outFile;
fp = fopen("products.dat", "rb");
outFile = fopen("allproducts.csv", "w");
Product p = malloc(sizeof(struct product));

while (fread(p, sizeof(struct product), 1, fp) == 1) {
    fwrite(p->code, sizeof(p->code), 1, outFile);
}
```

Problems are:

1. `p` is a pointer to struct as it is of type `Product` which is a pointer to struct, you need to allocate memory for it before you can use it
2. In `fread` you are passing `sizeof(Product)` which essentially passes the size of the pointer, whereas you want to read the sizeof the structure product.

The other problems which I haven't corrected is checking the return values of fopen,malloc etc which I leave it to you. : )

Answer (score 0):

Hiding pointers behind typedefs is error prone and leads to confusing code.

- `p` is defined as a pointer to a `struct product`, but is not initialized: passing its value to `fread` as the destination invokes undefined behavior.
- `sizeof(Product)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the structure.

Do not define `Product` as a pointer, make it a typedef for the structure if you can, or do not use the typedef if you cannot:

```
struct product {
    char code[15];
    char name[50];
    short int quantity;
    double price;
};

typedef struct product Product;
```

Adjust the code and write the string to the `csv` file, not the complete array of chars:

```
File *fp;
File *outFile;
fp = fopen("products.dat", "rb");
outFile = fopen("allproducts.csv", "w");
struct product prod;

while (fread(&prod, sizeof(prod), 1, fp) == 1) {
    fprintf(outFile, "%s\n", prod.code);
}
```

Note that this will be incorrect if the product code contains embedded spaces, `,`, `"` or newline characters.